# Is there a way to programmatically list deployed API's on AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have several API's hosted on AWS that sit behind API Gateway. They are deployed with the serverless framework.

Is there away for me to programmatically query for and retrieve a list of all the API's that are deployed?

Answer (score 0):

if your APIs are deployed as different stacks, you cannot use the `serverless` CLI command to list them.

but instead, You can use the AWS CLI command to list all the APIs powered by API gateway using the command below.

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may use [AWS SDK getRestApis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/AbstractAmazonApiGateway.html#getRestApis-com.amazonaws.services.apigateway.model.GetRestApisRequest-) service (I linked Java SDK, but you may use any language of your choice)